# Strange results after overriding hashcode() method

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the following situation-

1. I am creating a HashMap using generics. The key is of type TestHashMap, and the value is of type String.
2. In the main method of TestHashMap, I use three instances of TestHashMap as keys to store three different strings.
3. I override the hashcode() method so that it returns a different integer on each call.
4. Then I extract the keys in the HashMap and print out the corresponding values.

This gives me totally unexpected results- I get a ***null for each value*** of the three key-value pairs.

Note that if, instead of returning different integers on different calls of hashcode(), I just returned the same integer, everything works fine.

This has me really stymied. Any help will be much appreciated.

Here is the code. You should be able to run it if you copy it as is.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

public class TestHashMap {
    private static int hash = 0;    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<TestHashMap,String> h = new HashMap<TestHashMap,String>();
        TestHashMap thm1 = new TestHashMap();
        TestHashMap thm2 = new TestHashMap();
        TestHashMap thm3 = new TestHashMap();

        h.put(thm1, "one");
        h.put(thm2, "two");
        h.put(thm3, "three");

        Set<TestHashMap> keys = h.keySet();
        for(TestHashMap k : keys){
            System.out.println(k + " " + h.get(k));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){ return hash++;}
}
```

Comment: You haven't overridden `equals`... and your `hashCode()` method is unstable. (If you call it twice, it will never return the same value...) I suggest you revise the requirements for `hashCode()` and `equals`.

Comment: Why are they _totally unexpected_ results? What is a `hashCode` meant to do? How does `HashMap` use it?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29

Comment: Thanks to all of you. As I have said in reply to @William, I should have thought of retrieval and not just storage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- When you put an object into a map, the map will read the key's hashcode and place it into the appropriate bucket;
- when you later get an object by the same key, the map will *again* read the key's hashcode and look for an object *equal* to the key in that bucket;
- but your key gives the map a different hashcode each time. So the poor map is tricked into looking in the wrong bucket.

Comment: Ah, but of course!  Really clever of you to have found the problem immediately. Thanks.  P.S. And really stupid of me not to have thought of retrieval..

Comment: @user3516726, not really all _that_ clever, since every experienced Java programmer knows that whenever `a.equals(b)` you _must_ make sure that `a.hashcode()==b.hashcode()`.